# What exactly does a udp socket receive?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

```
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <netinet/udp.h>

  udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

when I use an UDP socket, do I receive just the payload or also the UDP header?

Comment: Just refer to the [`recv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) reference. Ie. you get the payload. The UDP protocol is handled for you.

Comment: If you want to know where the packet came from, there is `recvfrom` available in addition to `recv` function.

Comment: Socket returns a file descriptor which later on could be used to receive data using system calls , the datagram sockets would use sendto , receivefrom for sending/receiving , the logic for getting specific prtotocol is in implemented there, there you need to pass the socket descriptor

Comment: [`man 7 ip`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) is also a good reference for this sort of stuff if you're on a Linux/POSIX system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can or cannot access depends on how the socket is created.

Here is a comment in the docs relevant to your question:

> The recv() function shall receive a message from a connection-mode or
>   connectionless-mode socket. It is normally used with connected sockets
>   because ***it does not permit the application to retrieve the source
>   address of received data***.

(emphasis mine)

*[read more here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html)*...

*Edit*:  If accessing header information is what you want to do, read this and the following link.

> ...You cannot create a raw socket with IPPROTO_UDP and manipulate the UDP header; likewise with TCP. To manipulate the IP header as well as
>   either the TCP or UDP header (or any other protocol encapsulated in
>   IP), you must use the IP_HDRINCL socket option with a raw socket. ...

Read [more on the topic](https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedrawsocket11c.html)...

Comment: so it depends if I use recv or recvfom

Comment: @Maicake There may be a misunderstanding here.  Neither `recv` nor `recvfrom` will return the UDP header in the data.  `recvfrom` gives you the parsed source address via a separate channel.  If you want to read and parse the UDP header yourself, you have to open the socket in "raw" mode, I think.  (Perhaps `SOCK_RAW` instead of `SOCK_DGRAM`.)

Comment: @Maicake - I believe Steve Summit is correct.  If you are interested in how to use (access) UDP header information, [here is a tutorial discussing the topic](https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedrawsocket11c.html)  (and I have removed my previous comment as it was a misleading response to your comment.)

Comment: @SteveSummit - Your comment is correct.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: ok @SteveSummit so we agree that if I use an AF_PACKET socket with SOCK_RAW type I can read link level header information. If I use AF_INET  family socket I can just access the payload of the received UDP/TCP segment. That's because the packet travels more up through the network protocol stack. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Maicake - Your original post was not clear that you wanted to know how to access the header information. It rather implied you just wanted to know _what exactly does a udp socket receive?_. (Which is what I responded to.) It might help if you would edit your question to clarify that point.